# How to use the PHP different type comparison table?

Tags: php

I do not understand how to use this comparison table:
[image]

For example, I have

*"1hello">"bye"*

. What the algorythm do I have to use to compare them using this table?

Comment: haven't you ask basically [the same question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40126451/5309228) yesterday? also: posting a russian (i guess) screenshot on an english forum does not exactly increase your odds. have you tried http://ru.stackoverflow.com/ ?

Comment: yes, I posted this question on  ru.stackoverflow.com and other forums, but I do not have an unswer at the moment

Comment: on a further note - *what exactly are you trying to test*? with strings, the only basic operations that make any sense are `==` and `!=` you should try to be more precise in defining what you actually *want to do*

Comment: I want to know how to use this table above

Answer (score 1):

[The line just above the screenshot](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) in your question says

> For various types, comparison is done according to the following table **(in order)**.

So the first comparison is used (i.e. lexical comparison).

For the sake of completeness, `"1hello"` is considered **less than** `"bye"`, since the ordinal value of `1` (49) is less than that of `b` (98).

Comment: can you explain why did you make lexical comparison using the table in my question? the table says that there are TWO variants - line 1 (numberical or lexical comparison ) and line 4 (numberical comparison)

Comment: @Dimon Right, and as the documentation says, they are done **in order**. So the first one is used.

Comment: it is written in the first line -  "numerical or lexical comparison". two variants of comparison. what the variant do I have to choose?